# Auto-fill for whole form doesn't work inside iframe (google chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, autofill

I have two forms (ref https://jsfiddle.net/svejdo1/f7uwt6jo/12/)
Second form (the on the bottom) is inside iframe.

[image: Form image]

The autofill seems to work for both cases - i.e. if I type into "street" it allows me to select from "street" fields I recently submitted. However there is one significant difference - when I select email it also prefill the whole form with my profile - but just for the non-iframed form. When I attempt to do the same for iframed form it doesn't work.

[image: Form image]

Is there a trick to make it working ? Or is this a bug in chromium ? Or is this security feature of some sort ?

```
<form id="form" action="#">
  <label for="street">Street</label>
  <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />

  <label for="zip">ZIP</label>
  <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />


  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
  var cln = document.getElementById('form').cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('iframe')
   .contentWindow.document.children[0].children[1].appendChild(cln);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I am having the same issue and couldn't found the solution.